# Updating value and subtracting from it

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry this is pretty basic, I'm not very adept in VBA. 
All I want it is to have a button that when clicked stores an integer away and then subtracts the value from another value. For example, if value1 is = 100, you click the box and enter a number and it subtracts that number from 100. So let's say you enter 30, the number should become 70 and if you do it again it should go down to 40. Once the 100 runs out, display a msgbox. It's just a part of a project that I'm struggling with.

Comment: "stores an integer away" -- stores it *where* exactly? A VBA public variable? A cell on a spreadsheet? A workbook name? Where is "value 1" supposed to come from? Have you tried anything? If so, you should show your code and describe what problems you are having with it.

Comment: Yes a public variable. I've tried both storing it in a cell and storing it in a variable. I didn't share any code because it simply didn't work. Every time I would click the button everything resets. Maybe a loop is necessary?

Comment: posting your code even if it doesn't work is good practice to show that what you've already tried

Answer (score 1):

This might give you some ideas. In a standard code module enter:

```
Public balance As Long

Sub Deposit()
   'adds to the current amount
    balance = balance + InputBox("Please enter a value")
End Sub

Sub Withdraw()
    Dim v As Long

    v = InputBox("Enter a value, maximum of " & balance)

    If balance < v Then

        MsgBox "Sorry, that value is too big"
    Else
        balance = balance - v
    End If

    If balance = 0 Then MsgBox "Amount is exhausted"
End Sub
```

Attach these two subs to buttons and see how they work.

A word of warning about public variables -- if something causes your project to reset then you loose data. Storing values in cells doesn't have the same problem (but you do have to decide where to put them without cluttering your worksheet).